# python randint related syntax

Tags: python, syntax

```
import random

"1stdigit" = random.randint(0, 9)
"2nddigit" = random.randint(0, 9)
"3rddigit" = random.randint(0, 9)
"4thdigit" = random.randint(0, 9)

print ("1stdigit")
print ("2nddigit")
print ("3rddigit")
print ("4thdigit")
```

This is my code, I have asked everyone I know what the issue is but none of them can figure it any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: it highlights the end of the brackets and cant assign to literal there are different syntax errors when i take the speech marks away from 1stdigit 2nddigit etc

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: You can't start a Python identifier with a digit, or assign to a string literal. Why not simply `digits = [random.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(4)]`, rather than four separate values?

Comment: thank you jon my code is much more efficient :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

first_digit = random.randint(0, 9)

print (first_digit)
```

Use like this. You are assigning method have syntax error.

[Read this](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/variables.html) for variable assigning method.

Comment: Variables in python cannot start with a number.

Comment: import random

1stdigit = random.randint(0, 9)

print (1stdigit)

2nddigit = random.randint(0, 9)

print (2nddigit)

3rddigit = random.randint(0, 9)

print (3rddigit)

4thdigit = random.randint(0, 9)

print (4thdigit)




like this? because it now highlights 1stdigit as a syntax error

Comment: ah ok just got the number comment thx

Comment: Probably important to mention they're trying to assign to a string literal.

Comment: @SimonKirsten Thank you for your point. Updated.